# "Мои разочарованиЕ и доблесть" или "мои разочарованиЯ и доблесть"

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, определения, множественное-число, число

Здравствуйте, возникла острая дискуссия по правильному написанию. Не можем разобраться.
 " И не забывай мои разочарование и доблесть, что выжгли моё сердце"
Мой знакомый, учитель русского языка,утверждает, что в данном предложении ошибка, т.к " Мои значит они, множ.число", то есть должно быть разочарованиЯ,с чем я согласен. 
Другой же человек считает, что верно написание с окончанием на Е, т.к идёт перечисление. Кому верить?

Прошу отнестись к вопросу с пониманием. Я хочу разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Стилистичеси это предложение неудачно. Разве доблесть может выжигать сердце?
Его следовало вы перестроить, например так:

**И не забывай мою доблесть и моё разочарование, которое выжгло моё сердце.**

Но если обсуждать только грамматику вашего предложения, то мы можем руководствоваться правилами, описанными Розенталем (§ [195. Определение при существительных – однородных членах).](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm)

Однородные члены (разочарование и доблесть) стоят в единственном числе. 
Если нет особых причин, определение ставится в единственном числе: **моё разочарование и доблесть**.

Если поставить первый член во множественном числе (разочарования), то определение ставится во множественном числе: **мои разочарования и доблесть**.

Answer (score 1):

**И не забывай моё разочарование и доблесть, что выжгли моё сердце.**

Используем правило Розенталя, в котором говорится, что определение ставится в форме ед. числа, если ясно, что оно относится к обоим существительным. Здесь это очевидно.
[§195. Определение при существительных – однородных членах](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_05)

Но вообще говоря, тема всегда вызывает вопросы, потому что на решение влияют разные факторы:

1) Неясная семантика требует выбора ед. или мн. числа для определения. Например: построить **каменный** дом и гараж или построить **каменные** дом и гараж). В нашем случае семантика  ясная.

2) Желательно по возможности  не нарушать согласование в числе **рядом стоящих** слов (моё разочарование, в нашем случае нужно ед.число).

3) В современном языке семантический принцип преобладает над формальным (тогда нужно мн. число, но этот принцип не является решающим).

Answer (score 0):

Учитель прав. В данном случае - "мои" относится к слову "разочарования". Поэтому оба слова должны стоять во множественном числе (или оба в единственном). Если предполагается другой вариант, то правильнее будет сказать - "мое разочарование и моя доблесть". Как вариант - "мои разочарования и моя доблесть".